# custom authenticate and password encryption laravel 5

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-5, password-encryption

Currently, i'm working a laravel 5 project.
I want to use my custom encryption for passwords, so I made a function, and i try to use it.
First, I override the postLogin function, and I added the new password Encryption.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = $this->hashPassword($request->get('password'));
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = ['email' => $email, 'password' => $this->hashPassword($password)];

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $this->hashPassword($password)])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

As you can see in the code, I called the function hashPassword, and that works, but the problem is that "Auth::attempt" returns false always, despite I have the user in my database, with the right data.
Any solution please?
Thanks a lot
Kind Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution !!!

I changed "attempt" with "login", and it works well now :D

Thanks guys

Comment: You could update your question and put answer there, either write a comment below, Instead of replaying to your own question and approving it.

Answer (score 0):

try keeping the name ok password field other than 'password' such as 'mypass' or sth else.. auth automatically hashes the value you provide with password key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide plain text password:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is official reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#included-authenticating